# how to add withdraw and deposit functionality in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm sorry for this weird question i'm new to programming and i'm starting out with ruby on rails, ive been trying to build this basic banking application ive been stuck with adding withdraw and deposit functionality, below is my models

```
class BankAccount < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client
  validates :account_number, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :balance, presence: true, numericality: true
 before_validation :load_defaults

  def load_defaults
    if self.new_record?
      self.balance= 0.00
    end
  end

  def to_s
    account_number
  end
end
```

```
class AccountTransaction < ApplicationRecord
  TRANSACTION_TYPES=["withdraw", "deposit"]
  belongs_to :bank_account
  validates :bank_account, presence: true
  validates :amount, presence: true, numericality: true
  validats :transaction_number, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :transaction_type, presence: true, inclusion: {in: TRANSACTION_TYPES}
  before_validation :load_defaults

  def load_defaults
    if self.new_record?
    self.transaction_number =  SecureRandom.uu:id 
    end
  end
end
```

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :bank_accounts
    has_many :account_transactions
    validates :first_name, :last_name, :middle_name, presence: true
    validates :client_number, presence: true, uniqueness: true
    before_save :format_name
    
    def format_name
        self.first_name = self.first_name.upcase
        self.last_name = self.last_name.upcase
        self.middle_name = self.middle_name.upcase
    end
    
    def to_s
        "#{first_name}, #{last_name}, #{middle_name}"
    end
end
```

then this is my controller

```
class BankAccountsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @bank_accounts = BankAccount.all
  end

  def show
    @bank_account = BankAccount.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

i tired adding a withdraw and deposit functions that adds a subtracts from bankaccount.balance but i dont know how i will get the route and params from the transaction form

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

By *transaction form* I assume you’ve created a form for submitting these changes. In order to get your routes you’ll first need to ensure that you have created them within your `routes.rb` file.

Assuming you want these under the BankAccountsController, the addition would look something like:

```
post '/account/:id', to: 'bank_accounts#deposit, as: "deposit"
```

This will allow you to use the [path helper](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers) `deposit_path(BankAccount)` to get the desired path and pass in the `BankAccount`’s ID for processing. Just to be clear `BankAccount` would be the given user’s bank account.

This would then allow you to post to a `deposit` method you’ve added to the BankAccountsController

Comment: no i havent created a form

Comment: What are referring to as the “transaction form” then?

Comment: You’ll want to create a form as well then which will submit to this path. I could write about it but the rails documentation already does an excellent job of that https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-model-objects

Comment: Creating the form is not the issue, my problem here is how to implement the logic in the model

Comment: Where are you stuck? You’ll need to be a lot more specific for people to help you.

Comment: In general you’d: 1. Have the form submit to the path I mentioned (form would submit an amount and account_id) 2. The method which is posted to would then subtract or add to the user’s balance

Comment: There also exist bank account templates which you can take inspiration from. Ie https://github.com/rafaeljesus/bank_ror